# Specifying a generic model for inheritance in Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building an app using Mongoose and would like to be able to do the following:

1) A model `Fridge` contains a `groceries` field that is an array:

```
var Fridge = mongoose.Schema({
    groceries: { type: [Grocery.schema] }
});
```

2) The `Grocery` model is a generic one, to be inherited by other models:

```
var grocerySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String }
});
var Grocery = mongoose.model("Grocery", grocerySchema);
```

3) For example, a tomato is a grocery:

```
var tomatoSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    size: { type: Number }
});
var Tomato = Grocery.discriminate("Tomato", tomatoSchema);
```

Now, if I instantiate a tomato and try to save it in my fridge, the proper `Tomato` attributes disappear, because (I guess), the fridge expects a `Grocery` so only saves the `Grocery` attributes.

```
var tomato = new Tomato({ name: "a big nice tomato", size: 20 });
fridge.groceries = [tomato];
fridge.save(...)
// now fridge === { groceries: [{ name: "a big nice tomato" }] }
// and not { groceries: [{ name: "a big nice tomato", size: 20 }] }
```

I think it is the expected behaviour of Mongoose, and in many ways it makes sense, but I would prefer not to save my `Groceries` in a separate collection and keep references to it in my `Fridge` model. So I would like my fridge to hold instances of tomatoes, and not references to a `Grocery` object in a separate collection. **Is there a design pattern that would allow me to do that?**

Thank you for your answer. *(P.S: due to the proximity to dinner time, the models above have been given names purely for example's sake!)*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible right now. You are right in thinking you have to save tomato, which will put it in `groceries` and then you can reference that from `fridge`.

Comment: That's sad :( I am trying to think of a clever hack but saving references might just be easier then...